# How to make a perfect cube

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, I create a cube with scale 1,1,1. Position is 0,1,0.
Then I placed it above a plane which is 15,1,5000. Position is 0,0,0.
I checked if the cube is below 1 in Y-axis, this will mean to me that the cube fall on the plane. I can control this cube by going left or right. If I go to left, there's no issue. If I go to right, my position becomes 0.9999998~. This makes my checking of falling become true even though the cube is still on the plane. Somehow, the cube seems not be be a perfect cube. Hope someone can enlighten me on why is this happening. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you checking manually for "falling" ? Use colliders and rigidbodies, Unity is a game engine and handle that for you, don't try to implement things that already exists.

Comment: Actually I can just replace my checking of "below 1" to "below 0". But my point is that why it seems like the cube is not perfect 1x1x1. Somehow it's like 1x1x0.9999998 if I go to left. I just want to understand that.

Comment: I just want to add that I have tried to check the values if I press left. The values varies from 1.0000066-1.0000096.
If I press right, the value varies from 0.9999968-0.9999997.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the answer you want, but - in poor words - computers' arithmetic is finite (search for [floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)). So, the "perfect cube" that you're looking for does not exist in the finite representation a machine could perform.
Moreover, Unity has its own physics engine that (like all physics engines) approximates the calculus of real world during each operation (translation, rotation, scaling).

The only way in which you can overcome the problem is by doing comparisons not with exact values (0, 1) but with ranges.
To maintain "order" in the coordinate system of your scene you could also - at fixed intervals - "adjust" your values, so, for example, manually setting the coordinate value to 1 if it is between 0.95 and 1.05 (adjust the values with your world's coordinate system, of course).

**Related note**: in your comment you say "*But my point is that why it seems like the cube is not perfect 1x1x1. Somehow it's like 1x1x0.9999998*". The fact is that a VR system, like Unity, does not maintain the objects' size in memory, but their vertices' coordinates. You feel like the object's dimensions have changed due to the translation, but this is not true in a strict way: it's just a finite approximation of the vertices' values for their X, Y, Z.